# Shell script : Redirect sql query output to a file

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, sqlplus

Inside a shell script, I have written below

```
sqlq(){
result=`sqlplus -S sss/eee@sid < $1|grep -v '^$'`
echo $result
}

echo "select * from emp" > q.sql
sqlq q.sql
```

---

I need to direct the output to a file. I have tried spool inside q.sql like below but didn't work

```
echo "SPOOL /tmp/test.txt; select * from emp';SPOOL off" > q.sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
sqlq(){
result=`sqlplus -S sss/eee@sid < $1|grep -v '^$'`
echo $result
}

echo "select * from emp" > q.sql
sqlq q.sql
```

The `echo` and the variable in the `sqlq` function are not needed:

```
sqlq () {
  sqlplus -S "sss/eee@sid" < "$1" | grep -v '^$'
}
```

This will send the output of the function to standard output (as it did before).

When calling the function, you may redirect its output to a file:

```
cat >query.sql <<END_SQL
SELECT * FROM emp;
END_SQL

sqlq query.sql >result.out
```

The reason I'm using a *here-document* here is that it makes it very easy to create multi-line SQL queries:

```
cat >query.sql <<END_SQL
SELECT data.*
FROM data
  JOIN attributes ON (data.attr_id = attributes.attr_id)
WHERE attributes.name = "Example";
END_SQL
```

... for example.

Comment: thanks, but im calling sqlq() inside shell script.

Comment: You may do the same inside the script. just `sqlq q.sql >output.txt`.

Comment: that is not working..

Comment: @SrikanthYadake Does it not work in any particular way? Do you get an error message? What is the symptom?

Comment: finding issue with creating sql query with cat as mentioned by you, any other way to create sql query file?

Comment: @SrikanthYadake You may do it as you did before if you wish. Using a "here-document" (with `<<`) allows you to easily add multiple statements on separate lines, but for a simple select statement you could obviously use `echo 'select ...' >q.sql`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43398/discussion-between-srikanth-yadake-and-kusalananda).

Comment: log file is created whr its intended to but an empty file..
im have put like below in shell script

echo "select * from emp" > q.sql   sqlq q.sql

Comment: Are you able to the query from the command line as `sqlplus -S "sss/eee@sid" <q.sql`

Answer (score 1):

1. the output of a function can be redirected to a file, same as with any other command.  e.g.

```sh
echo "select * from emp" > q.sql
sqlq q.sql > emp.txt
```

2. I'd rewrite that function so that it didn't need a temporary file.  I'd also be inclined to leave out the `grep -v` (or make it optional). e.g.

```sh
sqlq() {
  local filter
  filter='cat'

  # very primitive, use getopts for real option handling.
  if [ "$1" == "--delete-blank-lines" ] ; then
    filter='grep -v "^$"'
    shift
  fi

  # each arg is piped into sqlplus as a separate command
  printf "%s\n" "$@" | sqlplus -S sss/eee@sid | $filter
}

sqlq --delete-blank-lines 'select * from emp' > emp.txt

# two sql commands:
sqlq 'select * from emp;' 'select * from foo' > empfoo.txt

# that last example works just as well as:
sqlq 'select * from emp; select * from foo' > empfoo.txt
```

3. Many improvements are possible - e.g. other useful options in the function include:

   - reading the sql commands from stdin rather than using `printf` if it detects it's being piped to
   - an option to read the sql from a file
   - abiltity to pass arbitrary options to the `sqlplus` command.